# Stripe: set date of invoice charge in subscription model

Tags: stripe-payments

Hi I have subscription

- I created checkout session with `mode=subscription` and `price model id`
- then redirect client to stripe checkout url for pay
- then I have web hook and I wait for `invoice.payment_succeeded`

After first invoice is pay, I need set date of charge next invoice.

For example I have 1 month plan, after first pay I need change date of next invoice 3 days before end of month.

How can I do it?
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `billing_cycle_anchor` parameter of the [Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-billing_cycle_anchor) object. To align with your current flow, you'd want to update the subscription 3 days before the end of the month, passing `billing_cycle_anchor: "now"` as your parameter.

Additional billing cycle options can be [found here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle).

Comment: Thx @John Ryan Cottam,

Could you please tell me how I could do it?

I need to tell the subscription exactly on which day to charge the next invoice, how can I do that?